# Pandas Dataframe - Min Function with Condition/Row Iteration/Prev Row Calculation

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration, min

I have a dataframe that has some start and end dates for records:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B' ], 
             'StartDate': ['01/01/2015', '01/01/2016', '06/01/2016','10/01/2017', 
                           '01/01/2015', '01/01/2016', '07/15/2016','10/01/2017'], 
               'EndDate': ['12/30/2015', '05/31/2016', '09/30/2017', '12/31/2018', 
                           '12/30/2015', '05/31/2016', '09/30/2017', '12/31/2018']})
df = df[['Key', 'StartDate', 'EndDate']]

print(df)
```

My output looks like this:

```
 Key   StartDate     EndDate
0   A  01/01/2015  12/30/2015
1   A  01/01/2016  05/31/2016
2   A  06/01/2016  09/30/2017
3   A  10/01/2017  12/31/2018
4   B  01/01/2015  12/30/2015
5   B  01/01/2016  05/31/2016
6   B  07/15/2016  09/30/2017
7   B  10/01/2017  12/31/2018
```

I need to know the earliest start date and the latest end date for each key. 
I did this (please let me know if there is a better way to accomplish this):

```
df_start = df.groupby('Key')['StartDate'].min().reset_index(name = 'StartDate')
df_end = df.groupby('Key')['EndDate'].max().reset_index(name = 'EndDate')

final = pd.merge(df_start, df_end, on = 'Key', how = 'left')
print(final)
```

This gave me this output:

```
  Key   StartDate     EndDate
0   A  01/01/2015  12/31/2018
1   B  01/01/2015  12/31/2018
```

Now, if you look at the key "B" in the original dataframe, you will see that the end date on line 5 is 05/31/2016 and the start date on line 6 is 07/15/2016, so these records are not consecutive. There is a break in dates of 1.5 months. In cases where there is a break in dates of more than 3 days, I need to return the earliest start date for the consecutive records only, so in this case the desired output would be:

```
Key   StartDate     EndDate
    0   A  01/01/2015  12/31/2018
    1   B  07/15/2016  12/31/2018
```

I've been trying to use 'shift' method to calculate the number of days between the start date of each row and the end date of the previous row, but not sure if I'm going in the right direction altogether.. Or should I be iterating over rows? I have hundreds of thousands records in my dataframe.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: One suggestion, use `final = df.groupby('Key').agg({'StartDate': 'min', 'EndDate': 'max'}).reset_index()` after you select the last consecutive records of each key.

Comment: This is fantastic! Replaces 3 lines of my code with one. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, you will need to create a marker to defined consecutive records,then groupby and drop duplicates:

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])

df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])

consec = (df.groupby('Key').apply(lambda x: x.StartDate - x.EndDate.shift(1) >= pd.Timedelta('3 day'))
            .cumsum().reset_index(drop=True))

(df.groupby(['Key',consec])
   .agg({'StartDate':'min','EndDate':'max'})
   .reset_index()
   .drop_duplicates('Key', keep='last')
   .drop('level_1', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  Key  StartDate    EndDate
0   A 2015-01-01 2018-12-31
2   B 2016-07-15 2018-12-31
```

Comment: Brilliant! This does exactly what I needed. Thank you! I'm a little fuzzy on how it's being accomplished though. Can you please clarify how cumsum() works here? My understanding is that `lambda x: x.StartDate - x.EndDate.shift(1) >= pd.Timedelta('3 day')` returns a boolean value True/False. The documentation on cumsum() is pretty non-existent..

Comment: @Tatiana Sure, I am using `cumsum` to create groups, I take the boolean series results and increment by one when True,  Thefore all the falses are grouped together and the next True increments and creates a new group. So in this case [F,F,F,F,F,F,T,F] generates [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1], hence A stays as one group but B is broken into two groups.

Comment: Scott, how did it know to increment by one and not 10 or 15? Is that a default value? Is there a place to indicate by how much you want it to increment? Sorry, just want to make sure I understand how this works..

Comment: Ok, I think I may know the answer.. is it because python sees booleans as integers so it just adds the numeric values of True/False? 0 for False and 1 for True.. That would add up.. So, if I iterate over column with numeric values, it will increment by the number I have in that row, am I on the right track of thought?

Comment: Can you create new question with the offending data and currently working code?

Comment: Wasn't sure how to approach this.. Created a new question. Thanks, Scott!

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means a Pandas expert, but I think I got something that does what you want. First I convert the dates to datetime:

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], infer_datetime_format=True)
print(df)
```

result:

```
  Key  StartDate    EndDate
0   A 2015-01-01 2015-12-30
1   A 2016-01-01 2016-05-31
2   A 2016-06-01 2017-09-30
3   A 2017-10-01 2018-12-31
4   B 2015-01-01 2015-12-30
5   B 2016-01-01 2016-05-31
6   B 2016-07-15 2017-09-30
7   B 2017-10-01 2018-12-31
```

Then determine the amount of time between the end and start dates within each group:

```
df['Break'] = (df.groupby('Key')
    .apply(lambda d: d['StartDate'] - d['EndDate'].shift(1))
    .reset_index(level=0, name='Break')['Break']
)
print(df)
```

result:

```
  Key  StartDate    EndDate   Break
0   A 2015-01-01 2015-12-30     NaT
1   A 2016-01-01 2016-05-31  2 days
2   A 2016-06-01 2017-09-30  1 days
3   A 2017-10-01 2018-12-31  1 days
4   B 2015-01-01 2015-12-30     NaT
5   B 2016-01-01 2016-05-31  2 days
6   B 2016-07-15 2017-09-30 45 days
7   B 2017-10-01 2018-12-31  1 days
```

Finding where the break is above our required cutoff:

```
cutoff = pd.Timedelta('3 days')
df['Break_above_cutoff'] = df['Break'] > cutoff
print(df)
```

result:

```
  Key  StartDate    EndDate   Break  Break_above_cutoff
0   A 2015-01-01 2015-12-30     NaT               False
1   A 2016-01-01 2016-05-31  2 days               False
2   A 2016-06-01 2017-09-30  1 days               False
3   A 2017-10-01 2018-12-31  1 days               False
4   B 2015-01-01 2015-12-30     NaT               False
5   B 2016-01-01 2016-05-31  2 days               False
6   B 2016-07-15 2017-09-30 45 days                True
7   B 2017-10-01 2018-12-31  1 days               False
```

Then I define this function to find the portion of a dataframe starting at the
last row containing true in a column:

```
def get_after_last_true(df, colname):
"""Gets the portion of the dataframe starting from the last occurance of 
   True in colname"""
   idx = np.where(df[colname])[0]
   if len(idx) > 0:
       return df.iloc[idx[-1]:]
   else:
       return df
```

Apply it to the groups:

```
trimmed = (df.groupby('Key')
         .apply(lambda d: get_after_last_true(d, 'Break_above_cutoff'))
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
print(trimmed)
```

result:

```
  Key  StartDate    EndDate   Break  Break_above_cutoff
0   A 2015-01-01 2015-12-30     NaT               False
1   A 2016-01-01 2016-05-31  2 days               False
2   A 2016-06-01 2017-09-30  1 days               False
3   A 2017-10-01 2018-12-31  1 days               False
4   B 2016-07-15 2017-09-30 45 days                True
5   B 2017-10-01 2018-12-31  1 days               False
```

Then just use groupby-apply to get a tuple of the max of EndDate and min of StartDate

```
result = trimmed.groupby('Key').apply(
    lambda df: (df['StartDate'].min(), df['EndDate'].max())
)
print(result)
```

result:

```
Key
A    (2015-01-01 00:00:00, 2018-12-31 00:00:00)
B    (2016-07-15 00:00:00, 2018-12-31 00:00:00)
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It really helped me understand what is happening step by step. I marked Scott's answer as correct because the second part of his code (after identifying records with break in dates) is more succinct.

Comment: yeah I like his better too actually, couldn't comment at the time since I didnt have enough points!